# retraining tensorflow and model definition of dense layers: why x is not overridden?

Tags: tensorflow, transfer-learning

Good evening everyone

I don't understand why the value of x is not overridden.
Isn't x reassigned?

```
x = layers.Flatten()(last_output)
x = layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu')(x)
x = layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)                  
x = layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)
```

Comment: It is overridden, but I think every layer remembers the previous layer its been given with `x`, and in the end `x` is a chain of layers, not just the last one.